# Regex to match the last float in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
translate3d(0px, -26px, 0px) scale(1);
```

And I have the following regex

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

The problem is that my regex just matches the last int number and not float. How to modify it in order to recognize also the last float number in a string?

Comment: `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!.*\d)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan your regex matches the first number, not the last :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match float number you can use following regex

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!.*\d)
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kH2eO1/3)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If the ending is always `);` then you can use [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/kH2eO1/4)

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\);$)
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kH2eO1/4)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @AndiPavllo : glad to help